# Restore entire previous version of xcode project

Tags: xcode, version-control

Source control in xcode allows comparison of versions of an **existing** file.

Can I restore a file I **deleted** eg. file existed in version 10, I'm now on version 15 and want to restore that file

Answer (score 1):

You cannot revert the entire project at once in Xcode, but you could do it from the terminal; just cd into the folder of your project and type git log to find the hash you're looking for, then do git checkout [hash].

To restore a single file look to View > Version Editor within XCODE